# Вернуть значение из метода, если не выполняются условия C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, методы, словари

Как правильно поступить в ситуации, в методе находится ряд условий, если они удовлетворяются, то возвращается значение из словаря. Как поступить, если ни одно из условий не проходит условие? 
Класс - модель данных:

```
public class SecondModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> FirstDepartment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> SecondDepartment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> ThirdtDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Провайдер

```
public class SecondManager
{
    private SecondModel _model;

    public enum Department
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор по умолчанию
    /// </summary>
    public SecondManager()
    {

        _model = new SecondModel()
        {
            FirstDepartment = new Dictionary<int, double>(),
            SecondDepartment = new Dictionary<int, double>(),
            ThirdtDepartment = new Dictionary<int, double>()
        };

        _model.FirstDepartment.Add(1, 30.2);
        _model.FirstDepartment.Add(2, 25.8);
        _model.SecondDepartment.Add(3, 45.67);
        _model.SecondDepartment.Add(4, 54.46);
    }

    double GetValuesByKey(Department department, int key)
    {
        if (department == Department.First && _model.FirstDepartment.ContainsKey(key))
            return _model.FirstDepartment[key];

        if (department == Department.Second && _model.SecondDepartment.ContainsKey(key))
            return _model.FirstDepartment[key];

        if (department == Department.Third && _model.ThirdtDepartment.ContainsKey(key))
            return _model.ThirdtDepartment[key];

        // Еcли ключа или направления не существует
        return ???;
    }

}
```

Может вернуть infinity?

Comment: Можно бросать исключение или сделать чтобы метод возвращал `double?` и возвращать `null`. Это уж как вам удобнее.

Comment: Вот так (сокращенная форма для примера) - `double? GetValuesByKey(Department department, int key) => null`

Comment: @trydex, поддерживаю идею или можно по аналогии чтоб метод возвращал Int32? и возвращать null, ну можно возвращать -1 и при этом будет выброшено исключение

Comment: @JDo, а условия где прорали

Comment: или сделать `bool TryGetValuesByKey(Department department, int key, out double values)`

Comment: Прям TryParse какой-то =))

Comment: Вы все серьёзно считаете что для ситуации которая не возможна, надо возвращать `double.Infinity`, `null`, `-1` или делать `Try..` метод? А мне почему-то кажется что однозначно надо бросать исключение

Comment: Если данный метод в указанном контексте, наверное вы правы. Если это на стороне сервера, то можно null вернуть и на клиенте просто обрабатывать.

Comment: Можно сделать две версии метода: одна возвращает null (или bool false) в случае ошибки, другая бросает исключение, по аналогии с `Parse`/`TryParse`.

Comment: @4per извечный холивар на тему того как обрабатывать ситуации с кривыми входными данными, введешь исключение и другой товарищ не посмотрев внутренности метода его не обработает и угробит работу своего участка программы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не люблю я нагороженные if-ы в подобных методах, я бы такой код написал и задокументировал т.к. поведение метода не совсем очевидно

```
/// <summary>
/// Возвращает значение по данному ключу в направлении если существует, в противном случае - возвращает null
/// </summary>
/// <param name="department">Направление</param>
/// <param name="key">Ключ</param>
/// <returns>Значение по данному ключу в направлении</returns>
double? GetValueByKey(Department department, int key)
{
    switch (department)
    {
        case Department.First when _model.FirstDepartment.ContainsKey(key):
            return _model.FirstDepartment[key];
        case Department.Second when _model.SecondDepartment.ContainsKey(key):
            return _model.SecondDepartment[key];
        case Department.Third when _model.ThirdtDepartment.ContainsKey(key):
            return _model.ThirdtDepartment[key];
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне ваш вариант понравился больше всего!

Answer (score 2):

Если отвечать на вопрос прямо, то в случае, если не один их всех возможных вариантов не выполнен, то нужно бросать исключение. На самом деле такая ситуация невозможна лишь на момент написания программы, но если позднее кто-то расширит `enum`, то тут уже и станет реальным нарваться на вариант, который не возможно полноценно предусмотреть на момент написания. Однако, возвращение всяких *вспомогательных значений*, типа `null`, `double.Infinity` или `-1` это нарушение семантики вашего метода --- `GetValuesByKey(Department department, int key)` не должен возвращать подобные значения-секреты. 
Поэтому в такой ситуации меняйте

```
return ???
```

на

```
throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"Данным приложением не предусмотрена работа с отделом {department}")
```

---

Но, в этом конкретном случае, мы стали заложником антипаттерна Enum-Switch (Подробнее [статья (хоть и спорная)](https://habr.com/post/312792/) на Хабрахабр). Нельзя с помощью Enum реализовать список значений, который по своей природе склонен к изменению.

Например, в царстве *Растения* 12 отделов. И это вряд ли измениться за время жизни приложения. А в компании N сегодня 3 отдела, а завтра расширение, сокращение или кадровая реформа, и как результат, совершенно другой состав и количество этих отделов.

Comment: Отличное примечание, добавил бы еще более радикальный пример, что у может стать 100500 отделов и придется заводить 100500 сущностей под них, однако к вопросу это имеет мало отношения

Comment: @yolosora В вопросе заложена ошибка проектирования, почему указание на этот факт не относится к вопросу по вашему мнению?